# short-term childcare in June/July in Europe

Tags: europe, children

As the remote working trend continues, I am planning to take my kids (all three of them under 7 year old) to Europe for two months to experience different culture and scenery.  We've never been to Europe. The plan is to live in a city or two for the entire time, and send them to day camps during the days so I can work as well.  However, most summer camps in Europe starts at late June or July. So I haven't found a summer camp for them to go in early June (or even late May).  So I'm here to ask your help to see whether there are other alternatives to summer camp for the kids.  Appreciated!

p.s. We haven't decided which city to go... but I mostly investigated Austria and a little bit of Denmark.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to hire a private childcare service; especially if your children do not speak German (Austria) or Danish (Denmark).

I'd look at some expats web site for the 2 countries you are looking for.

see: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  Do you mean asking expats in those countries what how do they arrange activities for their child?  While my kids don't speak German nor Danish, I'm not so sure about the private childcare service because they kind of lose the opportunities interacting with local kids.

Answer (score 1):

In Denmark, I would advise you to check the website of the [International House](https://ihcph.kk.dk/). They have a subsidiary in every bigger city and offer information on pretty much everything that expatriates might find interesting. FYI, childcare is a paid for service in Denmark, with prices from about DKK 3900 per month. The website [Life in Denmark](https://lifeindenmark.borger.dk/family-and-children/day-care/childcare-facilities-for-young-children) is also quite helpful. By the way, the level of English in Denmark is also quite high, you can easily communicate, same goes for Austria.
It might be a bit difficult to find a short-term offer but maybe you could find someone on a website for nannies? There might be someone who takes care of multiple children. This way, your kids would not miss out on meeting others, if that is your main concern.

Comment: You mention day camps. I think these are school vacation activities. 
If that is the case, you might want to look at the school term dates. Looking at Aalborg and Copenhagen in Denmark for example at this site: https://publicholidays.dk/school-holidays/ it appears that kids are in school 'til 27th/25th June. 
At this site, it appears that kids in Austria are in school 'til early July https://publicholidays.at/school-holidays/

Comment: Also, you mention that you intend to work remotely. Have you looked into the Visa requirements for this activity in the countries you're planning to visit?